# Converting JArray to String to be Written Into JSON file

Tags: android, json, json.net, xamarin

So, I have a JSON file in the device to read and write onto. I'm using JSON.NET on Xamarin Android. I read from the file as follows:

```
FileStream jsonfile = new FileStream(root + "/data.json", FileMode.Open);
string content;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (jsonfile))
    content = sr.ReadToEnd ();
var objects = JArray.Parse (content);
```

This way, I'm not creating a class for the JSON objects. It is automatically parsed into the JArray object. Then, I can read the data easily and directly like:

```
foreach (JObject obj in objects) {
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Property("name").Value.ToString());
}
```

But when it comes to writing the data into the JSON file. I tried the process backwards, as my logic suggests:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter (jsonfile))
    sw.Write(JsonConvert.ToString(objects));
```

Well it just doesn't work. Error clearly says "Can not write to stream file."

I'm pretty new in this. So probably I'm doing something very wrong. The thing is, data I'll read is pretty simple (even if it's a JArray) and I'm trying the simplest methods I can find possible.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the FileStream overload that specifies file permissions and use FileAccess.ReadWrite.

```
new FileStream(root + "/data.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

Answer (score 2):

Even simpler than streams, if you are going to read and write entire files anyway, then you can just use `File.ReadAllText()` and `File.WriteAllText()`.

To read:

```
JArray objects = JArray.Parse(File.ReadAllText(root + "/data.json"));
```

To write:

```
File.WriteAllText(root + "/data.json", objects.ToString());
```

Comment: above one was the right answer but this solution is better. thank you.